# Behavior of compare and swap with unguarded concurrent modifications

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, compare-and-swap

Say a certain thread is using a __sync_val_compare_and_swap on a certain memory location to atomically set a value. Another thread directly modifying this memory location without going through compare and swap operation. What would be the consistency guarantee in this case (for each thread?).

Answer (score 0):

The exact behavior will vary by architecture. You haven't specified what processor you're running on, and both whether `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` is implemented as an instruction on the processor (like `lock cmpxchg`) or through LL/SC instructions could have an effect on the observed behavior (though I only bring up LL/SC because it's more sensitive than CAS).

Furthermore, memory ordering guarantees will change the behavior: a system like ARM or Power may exhibit different behaviors than x86(-64) or SPARC. I recommend reading [Samy Al Bahra's ACM Queue article "Nonblocking Algorithms and Scalable Multicore Programming"](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2492433) for more information on how this could influence the behavior of your program, though I will touch on this a bit.

You also haven't said what exactly you're doing with the CAS operation. Is it just assignment? Are you implementing some lock-free data structure with a CAS-loop? It's unclear, and a better answer could be provided with a better question. I'm going to assume as little as possible to really make anything worth discussing, so let's assume we are actually doing read-modify-write in both threads and we're trying to increment. If we have the following:

```
volatile uint32_t i = 0;
bool stop = false;

void *
t0(void *arg __attribute__((unused)))
{
    volatile uint32_t snap;
    while (!stop) {
        snap = i;
        __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&i, snap, snap + 1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *
t1(void *arg __attribute__((unused)))
{

    while (!stop) {
        i++;
    }
    return NULL
}
```

We can't talk about consistency guarantees because there's nothing for anything to be consistent with. **This program is not consistent.** We can't speak of consistency guarantees within a thread either, though it should be obvious that sometimes `t0` will fail to increment the value.

This example is not so innocuous. Even with a processor intrinsic to increment a number stored in memory (assuming it is not in cache), we are forced to read that number from memory, increment the number, and write that number back. Our `t1` will always succeed in incrementing a value, but it will only sometimes be the value incremented by `t0`.

Why?

An increment is a read / modify / write operation, as is a CAS. `i++` translates to `inc (%rax)` and decomposes into read-from-memory, increment, write-to-memory, or whether it translates into those instructions directly, when and how memory is read and written varies per architecture.

It's possible that both the CAS and the increment succeed. The core that `t0` runs on may not have observed `t1`'s write to memory yet, especially on relaxed memory ordering architectures like ARM or Power. It's possible that this could theoretically cause `t0` to update to a value behind what `t1` has written to `i`.

The `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` implies a full memory barrier according to GCC documentation, but no such barrier is provided by the other thread.

We could solve this by adding a memory fence:

```
void *
t1(void *arg __attribute__((unused)))
{

    while (!stop) {
        i++;
        __sync_synchronize();
    }
    return NULL
}
```

This helps because we are now guaranteeing a total ordering of memory operations due to the full memory barrier placed by `__sync_synchronize`. We can still race between `t0` and `t1`, but if they do, we will only lose one of the increments, we will never "fall behind" as we did without the fence. That all said, there's still no consistency guarantee. All that is guaranteed now is that if both threads run, at least 1 increment occurs.

Whether this is consistent or correct depends on how you define consistent or correct. It is certainly "more correct" and "more consistent" than what we had before.

Of course if we want real correctness, we need both threads to use `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`. Because GCC inserts the memory barriers, this does actually guarantee correctness regardless of memory ordering semantics on the target architecture.

Finally, if you're writing this sort of code, I'd really recommend using [Concurrency Kit](http://concurrencykit.org). Its API is much more pleasant and comprehensive, and it doesn't imply memory barriers anywhere (which can have a positive performance impact when they aren't needed, makes code more explicit when they are, and allows one to use lighter-weight load- or store-only fences when possible).